# No me escribe nada en el TXT exportado

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, class, serialización

He creado la siguiente función para escribir en cada línea de un documento de texto plano la variable datosCuentaTexto.

Llamo a la función desde el main, me crea el archivo txt pero me lo deja en blanco. No me lanza ningún error.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
public void exportarDatos(){
    String datosCuentaTexto = "";
    
    try{
        FileWriter datosExportados = new FileWriter("ListadoClientesCCC.txt");
        
        BufferedWriter miBuffer = new BufferedWriter(datosExportados);
        //BufferedWriter miBuffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ListadoClientesCCC.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size(); i++){
            datosCuentaTexto = "Nombre: " + listaClientes.get(i).getCliente().getNombreCliente() + " " + 
                    listaClientes.get(i).getCliente().getPrimerApellidoCliente() + " " + 
                    listaClientes.get(i).getCliente().getSegundoApellidoCliente() + ", IBAN: " + 
                    listaClientes.get(i).getIbanCliente();
            miBuffer.write(datosCuentaTexto);
        }
        datosExportados.close();
        
    } catch(IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HUBO UN ERROR");
    }
}
```

listaClientes es una LinkedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dejo el código por aquí:

```
public void exportarDatos(){
String datosCuentaTexto = "";

try{
    FileWriter datosExportados = new FileWriter("ListadoClientesCCC.txt");
    
    BufferedWriter miBuffer = new BufferedWriter(datosExportados);
    //BufferedWriter miBuffer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ListadoClientesCCC.txt"));
    for (int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size(); i++){
        datosCuentaTexto = "Nombre: " + listaClientes.get(i).getCliente().getNombreCliente() + " " + 
                listaClientes.get(i).getCliente().getPrimerApellidoCliente() + " " + 
                listaClientes.get(i).getCliente().getSegundoApellidoCliente() + ", IBAN: " + 
                listaClientes.get(i).getIbanCliente();
        miBuffer.write(datosCuentaTexto);
    }
    miBuffer.flush()
    miBuffer.close()
    datosExportados.close();
    
} catch(IOException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HUBO UN ERROR");
}
```

}

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Eres un fenómeno!!! Pero dime, ¿cómo lo has solucionado? Veo a mayores de mi código la clausula "miBuffer.flush()" y "miBuffer.close();". Se que miBuffer.close() cierra el flujo pero la flush() no se para que es, ¿me lo podrías decir? Muchísimas gracias!!!!

Comment: Pues mira te comento,lo que vas escribiendo Con BufferedWriter se va almacenando en un buffer(El buffer es un espacio temporal de memoria física el cual se usa para almacenar información mientras se envía de un lado a otro) y bueno con flush lo que haces es liberar lo escrito en este.Quizás con el miBuffer.close() ya te llegaba para lo que necesitabas,pero es de buenas prácticas liberar esos datos almacenados en memoria por temas de efectividad.Me alegro que te sirviese de ayuda, un saludo.(otra cosa importante:al liberar escribe los datos en el archivo que indicaste)

Comment: muchas gracias. Eres un máquina!!